# Is it possible to disable the Libraries feature in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows-libraries

The new Libraries feature in Windows 7 creates what are essentially virtual folders — you can combine multiple document folders together into a single library that combines them all into a single folder, create new libraries, and access them from common file open dialogues.

Is it possible to disable the Libraries feature in Windows 7?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Funny, Lifehacker.com JUST posted a link to this article:

http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-libraries-feature-in-windows-7/

Comment: +1 - I emailed them asking this question! Awesome thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Yeah, great article from one of my favorite sites.

Comment: Could you please summarize the technique described in the link?

Answer (score 1):

[**How to Disable “Libraries” Feature in Windows 7?**](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-libraries-feature-in-windows-7/)